# Access .NET 5 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, development-environment

I'm fairly new to C# an dotnet and I'm struggling a bit with the environment. I'm working on **Windows 10 Professional**.

I have **Visual Studio Community 2019** installed with Development .NET Desktop ticked.
I then installed successfully both **.NET 5.0 SDK and runtime**. When I go to a terminal and type `dotnet -v`, I get **5.0.401**.

However when I create a Console App (.NET Framework) project, I get the choice between .NET Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1,4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2 and 4.7.2! I don't see my .NET 5 framework! How can this be?

If I chose ASP.NET Core Web App, I do get the choice between .NET Core 3.1 (Long-term support) and .NET 5.0 (Current).

There's obviously something I don't understand. Is there a difference between the .NET version for Console/Windows app and for Web App? Am I doing something wrong in the installation or configuration?

Comment: Because ".NET Framework" (emphasis on "framework") is everything before "5", which, is not to be confused with .Net Core. Do you have just "Console Application" in the list?

Comment: No, I have all sort of things: Cloud, Console, Desktop, Extension, Games, IoT, Library, Machine Learning, Mobile, Office, UWP, Web... Many of them just then allow me to pick the frameworks mentioned above. When I select Web, I do see .NET 5.0. So, isn't it supposed to be a "Framework 5.0" or has the framework version number nothing to do with the .NET versioning number? I'm still confused.

Comment: `.NET 5` should IMO really have been called **`.NET Core 5`**, because it is the successor to **`.NET Core 3.1`**. Unfortunately some marketing people thought it would be a great idea to confuse as many people as possible by removing the Core part (at the same time *keeping* it for EF Core 5 and ASP .NET Core 5)..... .NET Framework (all versions) is old technology, and while still used a lot, there will be no real investment or further additions from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When are you are trying to create a console application you can choose between Console Application (.NET) and Console Application (.NET Framework)

For example:

```
dotnet new console -n "MyConsoleProject"
```

will create a .net 5 console application which you can open with visual studio

.NET Framework and .NET Core (or just .NET nowadays) are different. **.NET Framework 5** does not exist, there is a nice table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) with all the versions of the .NET platform

.NET is a continuation of .NET Core (a cross-platform library which ended with .NET Core 3.1)
.NET Framework is completely separate and only targets the windows platform

Answer (score 0):

As you man know, there is `.NET Framework`, and there is `.NET` (Previously called `.NET Core`). So make sure you don't confuse between `.NET Framework` and `.NET`
Currently in Visual Studio, whatever project type you find while creating a project is by default `.NET` unless it clearly specify `.NET Framework`. In your case, when you see **Console Application**, it means `.NET`. If you want the `.NET Framework`, you need to select **Console App (.NET Framework)**